# SAS Macro Do LOOP

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I want to have a sas macro loop by even years, so the do loop would jump from 2006 to 2008 to 2010...all the way to 2018 and not from 2006 to 2007.

When I do a %by = 2, SAS doesn't work and gives me an error message. What is the best solution?

I have the following Code:

```
%macro import;
    %do I = 2006 %to 2018;
        data BTI&I;
            set edited.Bti_&I;
            year=&I;
        run; 
    %end;
%mend import;
%import;
```

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work. `%do i=2006 %to 2018 %by 2;` should work fine.

Comment: And if you're just adding year perhaps there are better ways to get this done. INDSNAME is one option.

Comment: Hi Tom...I used that very exact code and i get the following error message: 

          ERROR: The %BY value of the %DO I loop is zero.
          ERROR: The macro IMPORT will stop executing. 

Here is the full code: 
                   %macro import;
                               %do I = 2006 %to 2018 %by = 2;
                                data BTI&I;
                     set edited.Bti_&I;
                         year=&I;
                                  run; 
                          %end;
                %mend import;
                %import;

Answer (score 3):

Add the `%by 2` keyword to increment intervals of 2. I would also recommend passing the start and end years as parameters to your function and give defaults values of 2006 and 2018.

```
%macro import(start=2006, end=2018);
    %do I = &start. %to &end. %by 2;
        data BTI&I;
            set edited.Bti_&I;
            year=&I;
        run; 
    %end;
%mend import;
%import;
```

Usage:

- `%import();` which will use the default values 2006 & 2018
- `%import(start=2009, end=2018);` specify the date range you want to use

Comment: You could further improve it by making the `by` value a parameter of the macro too.