# SAS macro loop to read csv files with proc import

Tags: import, sas, data-cleaning, sas-macro

I have a directory of csv files, each with names that begin with the letter m and end with a number. There are twelve files - m6 to m17.

I'd like to read them in and process them as separate data sets. I've written two macros attempting to do so. Macro1 works. Macro2 breaks. I would prefer Macro2 if I can get it to work, to avoid unnecessary bits like my creation of %rawfiles, invocation of %sysfunc, etc.

Macro 1:

```
%let rawcsv = C:\ALL\dat\;

%let rawfiles = m6 m7 m8 m9 m10 m11 m12 m13 m14 m15 m16 m17;

%macro1;

%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&rawfile));
    %let rawfile = %scan(&rawfiles, &i);

proc import datafile="&&rawcsv.&&rawfile.csv" 
                 out=&rawfile replace
                dbms=csv; 
        guessingrows=500; 
run;
%end;
%mend;

%macro1;
```

Macro 2:

```
%let rawcsv = C:\ALL\dat\;

%macro macro2(first=6, last=19);
%do i=&first. %to &last. %by 1;
proc import datafile="&&rawcsv..m&&i.csv" 
                 out=m&i replace 
                dbms=csv; 
        guessingrows=500;
run;
%end;
%mend;

%macro2;
```

%macro2 is my bad imitation [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660035/sas-macro-do-loop) solution. It returns the following errors:

```
MPRINT(MACRO2):   proc import datafile="C:\ALL\dat\m.6.csv" out=m.6 replace 
dbms=csv;
MPRINT(MACRO2):   ADLM;
MPRINT(MACRO2):   guessingrows=500;
MPRINT(MACRO2):   run;

ERROR: Library name is not assigned. /*repeats this error 14 times, once per file*/
```

Two questions:

1. What am I missing in %macro2?
2. Do you see a better solution that I am not using? The files are structured differently and not stackable, just a heads up.

Comment: Run your second macro with the MPRINT option on and post the log from one of the loops that generates the error. `options mprint;`

Comment: FYI - if you use PROC IMPORT it'll guess at the types. If you need to ever combine these files or process them you will not be able to assume that all variables were read in with the same data types so that will be an extra check you'll have to make or factor in to your process. If this is one time, it's just tedious, if this needs to run regularly that's definitely more work.

Comment: It's & not % in front of the LAST macro variable in your code. `%do i=&first. %to %last` should be &last, not %last.

Comment: Why so many `&` in both programs?  You appear to trying to reference a macro variable named `rawcsv`. What does that macro variable contain?

Comment: && was to refer to a macro variable within quotes, but I didn't include the &rawcsv content originally. I just updated the post - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your log we can see a period is being inserted into the output dataset name.  Just remove that extra period in your macro definition.

```
MPRINT(MACRO2):   proc import datafile="C:\ALL\dat\m.6.csv" out=m.6 replace dbms=csv;
```

The extra `&` in the code is probably confusing you.  When the macro processor sees two `&` it converts them to one and then reprocesses the string to further resolve the resulting macro variable references.

The period after a macro variable name is not required when the macro processor can tell that the name has ended. But the periods are needed in some places.
One place in your code is where it is required to make sure the macro processor knows where the name ends (the macro variable is named `readcsv` not `readcsvm` ). Another is where you want to place an actual period after the value of a macro variable.  You will need to place two periods there since the first will be used by the macro processor when it evaluates the macro variable value.

In this version of macro2 I have removed the periods after the macro variable names in the places where they are not required just to emphasize the places where the period is required.

```
%let rawcsv = C:\ALL\dat\;

%macro macro2(first, last);
%local i ;
%do i=&first %to &last ;
proc import dbms=csv
  datafile="&rawcsv.m&i..csv" 
  out=m&i replace 
; 
  guessingrows=500;
run;
%end;
%mend macro2;

%macro2(first=6, last=19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Small typo here, you need to use an & in front of LAST not the %.

```
 %do i=&first. %to %last. %by 1;
```

Should be:

```
 %do i=&first. %to &last. %by 1;
```

Unless you're using a separate macro called last to determine your end of the loop. But in that case you likely wouldn't also have a parameter called last.

If you're looking for alternate options I usually recommend reading all at once using a data step or CALL EXECUTE instead of macro loops as they're infinitely easier to debug in my opinion.

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-do-I-write-a-macro-to-import-multiple-text-files-that-have/ta-p/223627

Comment: Good catch - the macro still isn't resolving, so I have updated the code and the error.

Comment: MPRINT made the issue clear. My use of ampersands and periods were off, and I wasn't suffixing the input file name with csv. Feel free to point out the ".." issue in my last revision of the question so I can accept this answer.